# PHP Web service connect with mssql sqlite and mysql

Tags: web-services

I getting difficulty proceeding with this project if anyone can help.

i am coding a web service at will connect 3 database at the same time.

please check the picture so that you have an idea what am talking about.

http://i57.tinypic.com/j5w1sk.png

So there three data base will be exchanging information. input will obviously come from the android app where info will be entered. info from android app will be send xml file to webservice for processing. part of the info will go to mssql and part will go to mysql. sorting of info will be done by the webservice.

Comment: There isn't an actual question here...

Comment: It looks like a request for free consultancy :)

Comment: my question where to start or if there is an open source webservice i can use